# Show next and prev image partially in carousel with different width in the center

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to make a slider like this using jQuery (not using wordpress).

Please see [Slider example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i600e.jpg) and [Slider example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LomZ7.jpg)

I have been trying to use slick carousel and it seems that the `centermode` and `variablewidth` settings combined cannot give the effect I want (the image isn't placed in the center).

I also have tried other slider but the center image cannot have different width.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options

If you want the image to take up entire carousel then

```
img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

If you dont want the image to stretch 100 %, then set your desired width(or dont, just specify margin) and margin auto:

```
img { width: 50%; margin: auto; }
```

If you are using default bootstrap carousel

```
.carousel-inner .item a img {

margin: auto;

}
```